# Parallelize USB data? Or simply use LPT?

Tags: usb, interrupts, rj-45, lpt, msp

I need to generate a simple system in which host computer interrupts lead out to a non-standard RJ-45 connection (6 pins in binary on/off state) that can be triggered with little latency. The only outputs available on the host is an ethernet controller and USB. All that the pins on the RJ-45 need to do is slew 2.5V with +-0.5 hysteresis. Some research has indicated to me that the one option in this case would be to get a dev board that can handle a USB stack (ex: TI MSP430 5xxx series) and solder the GPIO pins to an RJ-45 cable to achieve this effect, but I'm wondering if there is an easier solution. One possibility I could think of was using a PCI-express parallel port card instead and simply construct a 6-wire parallel to RJ-45 cable, and use LPT to control which RJ-45 pins are active. If anyone has any experience with coding, which is the simpler solution to implement? Are there any other methods to do trigger the activation of 6 pins in parallel with a computer with the stated outputs? Thank you.

Addendum - I should add that the goal isn't to parallelize packetized data from USB. They can be simple character string triggers, I just need a way to identify which pin on the RJ-45 needs to be "active" from the host. More an more I'm thinking just buying a parallel port card is the answer but I'm still interested in what opinions people might have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use a USB to parallel port adapter with a little cable adapter to give an RJ-45 port.

Comment: Does the host "see" these adapters as a standard LPT interface? i.e. could I use something like [WndLpt](http://wndlpt.sourceforge.net/) I just need the ability to set specific pins to active. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Yes, that's correct.